# Is it possible to add views to layout in onLayout event?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Is it possible to add views to a layout during the onLayout event of one of its Childs?

i.e.

FrameLayout contains View, in View.onLayout() I want to add views to the parent FrameLayout.

This is because the views I need to draw on the FrameLayout needs the child View dimensions (width, height) to assign them to particular positions on the FrameLayout.

I already try to do so, but nothing is getting drawn. Do you know how can I accomplish the same effect? or if I'm doing something wrong. Don't know why I'm unable to draw the views, event if I call invalidate.

Thanks.

Comment: onLayout can be called a number of times, so it is probably not a wise point at which to add children. Better to add them at the beginning, then just change their position/size in `onLayout`

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your comment. I'm creating the views outside of the onLayout event. However, I'm not able to change its LayoutParams on onLayout event, I need to do so in order to put this views in particular positions within the FrameLayout. Any thoughts?

Comment: Because now the views are getting displayed, but always in the top-left corner of the FrameLayout

Comment: Setting the `LayoutParams` of the children will have no affect unless you change the layout behaviour of `FrameLayout`, since it only places children in the top-left corner regardless of their requested position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I have solved similar problem (placing a checkpoint Button into FrameLayout over SeekBar) using the following code (overriden methods from SeekBar):

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int left, final int top, final int right, final int bottom) {
  super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
  View child = new Button(getContext());

  //child measuring
  int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(mWidthMeasureSpec, 0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //mWidthMeasureSpec is defined in onMeasure() method below
  int childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);//we let child view to be as tall as it wants to be
  child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

  //find were to place checkpoint Button in FrameLayout over SeekBar
  int childLeft = (getWidth() * checkpointProgress) / getMax() - child.getMeasuredWidth();

  LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  param.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
  param.setMargins(childLeft, 0, 0, 0);

  //specifying 'param' doesn't work and is unnecessary for 1.6-2.1, but it does the work for 2.3
  parent.addView(child, firstCheckpointViewIndex + i, param);

  //this call does the work for 1.6-2.1, but does not and even is redundant for 2.3
  child.layout(childLeft, 0, childLeft + child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)    {
  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  //we save widthMeasureSpec in private field to use it for our child measurment in onLayout()
  mWidthMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec;
}
```

There is also [ViewGroup.addViewInLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addViewInLayout%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) method (it's protected, so you can use it only if you override onLayout method of your Layout) which javadoc says its purpose is exactly what we discuss here, but I haven't understood why is it better than addView(). You can find it's usage in [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

Comment: Talking about addViewInLayout, you can see the difference in the source code: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L3405 & https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L3535

Plus there is a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17206638/553941